DAX Absolute min(date) of var = table when matrix has date related rows
I am looking for the absolute minimum date of a var table ignoring the date related field in the output matrix
Here is the measure I created
earliers_date =
var A =  SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                ALL('Date'[Week Ending]),
                "V", [Vol]),
                
            [V] <> BLANK ()
                || [v] > 0
), [Week Ending])

VAR b = SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(addcolumns( a, 
        "@R", RANK(
                    DENSE,
                    a,
                    ORDERBY ( [Week Ending] , ASC ),
                    ,
                    )
        ), [@R] = 1), [Week Ending])

RETURN B

Here is what I get in PowerBI as output

I want the Earlierst_date to be in everyrow "1/6/2019 12:00:00 AM" and not change from row to row

could you pls provide some sample data?

CALCULATE( MIN('FactTable'[Date]), ALL('DimDate') )
(You need to remove the MonthYear column from the evaluation context).
